# Does open loop stability guarantee an MPC stability?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, optimal-control, stability

In the following publication

```
Arce, A., Alejandro, J., Bordons, C., & Ramirez, D. R. (2010).
"Real-time implementation of a constrained MPC for efficient 
airflow control in a PEM fuel cell."
IEEE Transactions on Industrial Electronics, 57(6), 1892-1905.
```

There is a claim that

> In fact, as the fuel cell is open-loop stable and the input signal is bounded, the closed-loop system is stable, at least in the bounded-input–bounded-output sense.

However, I doubt this claim is true for a **Model Predictive Control (MPC)**. But, I do not have a counter example too.

Could anyone please inform if this claim is correct or any counter example exists.

Comment: I think that open loop stability does not ensure the constraints will always be satisfied, for example when a too short horizon is used.